# Local storage in a stream Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to write a stream method that may need to ignore several concurrent values based on a "lastGoodVersion" but I can't find a way to share the value within the stream.  Below is what I'd LIKE to do.  Any suggestions on how to accomplish something like this?

[EDIT don't do this, it's not how java streams work]

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what result you actually want?  It's not clear from the code whether you're simply looking for the "best" answer (the last canonical version after processing), or the maximal sorted subsequence of a set of candidate entries (hard to imagine why you'd want this, but that's closest to the code you posted.)

Comment: Streams are not always the best possible solution for anything that involves a loop... This looks like a problem that could be solved in a much more clear and easy way with a simple `for` loop instead of a stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible using only Java 8 Streams. A possible solution to what you want to do could however use a helper function which may look something like this:

```
private static <T> Stream<T> progressiveFilter(Stream<T> stream,
                                               BiPredicate<T, T> predicate) {
    List<T> list = stream.collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<T> result = new ArrayList<>();
    T previousValue = null;
    for (T entry : list) {
        if (previousValue == null) {
            previousValue = entry;
        } else {
            if (predicate.test(entry, previousValue)) {
                result.add(previousValue);
            } else {
                previousValue = entry;
            }
        }
    }
    if(previousValue != null) {
        result.add(previousValue);
    }
    return result.stream();
}
```

The call you are trying would then look something like this:

```
progressiveFilter(
    allVersionsStream().filter(NSTimestamp::isApproved),
    (v, lastCanonicalVersion) -> !v.isEffectiveBefore(relativeDate)
                               && v.isEffectiveBefore(lastCanonicalVersion));
```

Quite possibly this can be further optimized. But the principle, I hope, is clear.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, you won't be able to modify a local variable from lambda body. You need a wrapper of some kind that contains the thing you want to modify. An array is often used for that purpose

```
VERSION[] lastCanonicalVersion = {null}

....

                            if(...lastCanonicalVersion[0]...)
                                lastCanonicalVersion[0] = v;
```